# Why does using only name of character array prints the whole array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

why does this print the whole array:

```
char d[6] = "jelly";
cout << d << endl;
```

While this doesn't?

```
int e[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
cout << e << endl;
```

Comment: Because in `C`, a "character array" is a string, while an integer array is not.

Comment: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/

Comment: Because `std::ostream` has special `operator<<` for `const char *`